# How do you get that normal style location not available in IOS?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

Say I turn off location in map. I go to map. Apple would pop something and says that location is not available. When user press settings it goes to settings.

How do we pop that message?

I know I can use UIAlertView. However that message seems to be apple standard. Also when pressing settings people go to setting straight. I do not see how I can make something like that my self or can I?

It seems that Apple simply display that pop up automatically when we try to get location but don't have permission to do so.

Well, not in my case. In my case if the app doesn't have permission to do so, it'll just hang waiting for permission that never come.

Answer (score 1):

The first time the app wants to use location services, the system will show that alert. The user has the choice to enable it, but that alert will not be shown again. As a developer, you also don't have the ability to show it again.

What you could do, is check the `authorizationStatus` on `CLLocationManager`:

```
if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] != kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
    // show alert telling the user to enable location services for this app
}
```

You can't directly open the Settings app though.

Comment: That's the thing. The first time my app use location services the system doesn't show that alert!!!

Answer (score 0):

Check the location services are enabled or not.If location services is not enabled so create a own UIAlertView with location serives massage.

```
if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] && 
     [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] != kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied)
{
    // Show alert 
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex  
{
    if(alertView.tag == 1)
    {
        // set Url 
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES"]];


    }
}
```